# How to count only negative, from right to left, only in sequence, stop count if positive value appear

Tags: microsoft-excel

In an Excel spreadsheet, I have six cells (`A1`-`F1`) containing numbers. 
I want to count consecutive (contiguous) negative values, from right to left. 
e.g.,

```
A1=2,  B1=6,  C1=-3, D1=-5, E1=-6, F1=-9  : Answer G1=4  (four continuous negative values)
A1=2,  B1=6,  C1=3,  D1=5,  E1=-6, F1=-9  : Answer G1=2
A1=2,  B1=-6, C1=3,  D1=5,  E1=-6, F1=-9  : Answer G1=2
A1=-2, B1=-6, C1=-3, D1=5,  E1=6,  F1=-9  : Answer G1=1
A1=-2, B1=-6, C1=-3, D1=3,  E1=-6, F1=-9  : Answer G1=2
```

Or, a similar situation but with words,
I want to count how many consecutive cells contain `RED`,
starting from the right:

```
A1=GREEN, B1=GREEN, C1=GREEN, D1=GREEN, E1=RED,   F1=RED  : Answer G1=2
A1=GREEN, B1=GREEN, C1=RED,   D1=GREEN, E1=RED,   F1=RED  : Answer G1=2
A1=GREEN, B1=RED,   C1=RED,   D1=GREEN, E1=GREEN, F1=RED  : Answer G1=1
A1=GREEN, B1=RED,   C1=RED,   D1=RED,   E1=RED,   F1=RED  : Answer G1=5
```

I want to count from right to left, until the specific series breaks.

Comment: Are there any other sequences? How about A1=4, B1=6, C1=15, D1 =3, E1=7, F1=2: Answer G1=3 because the three values on the right are prime numbers.

Comment: @Blackwood: Why are you asking whether the OP also has some other question in addition to the one he actually asked?

Answer (score 1):

Type

```
=6-MAX(IF(A1:F1>=0, COLUMN(A1:F1), 0))
```

into `G1` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. 
Given your first example (A1 = 2, B1 = 6, C1 = −3, D1 = −5, E1 = −6, F1 = −9),
the `IF(X>=0, COLUMN(X), 0)` subexpression
creates a virtual array that looks like (1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0)
— replacing non-negative numbers with their column numbers,
and replacing negative numbers with zero. 
Taking the `MAX` of that gives us the last (right-most) column
that contains a non-negative number —
so everything beyond that must be negative. 
So subtracting that from 6 tells us
how many (consecutive) negative numbers there are
at the right end of the series.

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
makes it an array formula. 
That’s necessary to be able to create a virtual array like that.

For the alternative version of the question,
the solution is almost exactly the same:

```
=6-MAX(IF(A1:F1<>"RED", COLUMN(A1:F1), 0))
```

[image: spreadsheet with OP’s input data and desired results]

Answer (score 0):

For a formula that can be entered as normal formula, try:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:F1>=0),{5,4,3,2,1,0}),6)
```

The LOOKUP matches the last entry that tests `TRUE`
We then return the appropriate count from the array.

However, if all the values are `<0`, then the `LOOKUP` returns an error, so we must have six.